# Template typedef?

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

In an external API, I have structs defined:
`Foo1`, `Foo4`, `Foo8`, `Foo16`

Now I need to define four functions:

```
void bar(Foo1*);
void bar(Foo4*);
void bar(Foo8*);
void bar(Foo16*);
```

These functions do the same thing in a loop iterating 1, 4, 8 and 16 times.

In order to avoid writing these functions 4 times, I would be happy to define them with a template:

```
template<unsigned int N> void bar(Foo<N> * foo)
{
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<N;++i)
    {
        //Some critical code that optimizes nicely with SSE, AVX, etc...
    }
}
```

But, I don't know how to define the template class `Foo<N>` so that it's specialized to `Foo1`, `Foo4`, `Foo8`, `Foo16`

Is it possible?

I know that I could create a template struct:

```
template<unsigned int N> struct Foo;
template<> struct Foo<1>{ Foo1 f; };
template<> struct Foo<4>{ Foo4 f; };
template<> struct Foo<8>{ Foo8 f; };
template<> struct Foo<16>{ Foo16 f; };
```

This would be functionally identical to what I want to achieve, but bloats somewhat the `bar` code, which will be full of `foo.f`s, and relies on a cast from `FooN*` to `Foo<N>*`.

Comment: Thanks to all answers! I learned a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know how to define the template class Foo so that it's specialized to Foo1, Foo4, Foo8, Foo16

Like this:

```
template <int N> struct Foo_impl {};
template <> struct Foo_impl<1 > {using type = Foo1 ;};
template <> struct Foo_impl<4 > {using type = Foo4 ;};
template <> struct Foo_impl<8 > {using type = Foo8 ;};
template <> struct Foo_impl<16> {using type = Foo16;};
template <int N> using Foo = typename Foo_impl<N>::type;
```

But the problem is that template argument deduction is not going to work with such an alias:

```
template <int N> void bar(Foo<N> *foo) {}

int main()
{
    Foo<4> x;
    bar(&x); // error: no matching function for call to 'bar'
             // note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'N'
}
```

To make it work, you have to use something like `template <typename T> void bar(T *foo) {}`, with a `static_assert` (or some other trick) to restricts `T` to one of those 4 types.

You can do something like this:

```
template <typename T> void bar(T *foo)
{
    constexpr int N =
        std::is_same_v<T, Foo1 > ? 1  :
        std::is_same_v<T, Foo4 > ? 4  :
        std::is_same_v<T, Foo8 > ? 8  :
        std::is_same_v<T, Foo16> ? 16 : throw "Invalid T.";
    // ...
}
```

Here, `throw "Invalid T."` doesn't actually throw at runtime, but causes a compile-time error if `T` is not one of `Foo#`.

Answer (score 2):

For running your loop depending of the class, you can use a constant expression starting with C++11:

```
template<typename T>
void bar(T) {
    constexpr unsigned int N = std::is_same<T, Foo4>::value * 4 + std::is_same<T, Foo16>::value * 16; // likewise for Foo1, Foo8
    // ...
}
```

The expression is evaluated at compile time, so N is known at compile time as well. If the method is called with a class not covered, in that instantiation of the method, N is 0. You can use a `static_assert` to check for this at compile time:

```
static_assert(N > 0, "bar() called with object of invalid type");
```

**Putting it all together** for the four classes, it would look like this:

```
template<typename T>
void bar(T *a) {
    constexpr unsigned int N = std::is_same<T, Foo1>::value * 1
        + std::is_same<T, Foo4>::value * 4
        + std::is_same<T, Foo8>::value * 8
        + std::is_same<T, Foo16>::value * 16;
    static_assert(N > 0, "bar() called with object of invalid type");

    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

That's it!

For another way of restricting use of the function at compile time, you can use `std::enable_if` to reduce the scope of your specialization to the four types:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same<T, Foo4>::value || std::is_same<T, Foo16>::value)>
bar(T *a) {
    // code
}
```

This uses the return type to make the function only compile if instantiated with an allowed type (Foo4 or Foo16). Starting with C++17, you might also use [`std::disjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction).

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this? Specialize the function, and not the type itself:

```
template<typename FooT, unsigned N>
void bar_impl(FooT f)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        //Do magic!
    }
}

template<typename FooT>
void bar(FooT f);

template<>
void bar<Foo1>(Foo1 f)
{
    bar_impl<Foo1, 1>(f);
}
template<>
void bar<Foo4>(Foo4 f)
{
    bar_impl<Foo4, 4>(f);
}
template<>
void bar<Foo8>(Foo8 f)
{
    bar_impl<Foo8, 8>(f);
}
template<>
void bar<Foo16>(Foo16 f)
{
    bar_impl<Foo16, 16>(f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a helper struct `bar_trait` that you specialize for each of the type `Foo1`, `Foo4`, … . Those specializations can then hold various values that you can then use in your `bar` function to control your code flow.

That way `bar` can accept any type for which you create a specialization of `bar_trait` and that supports the expression you apply on it in `bar`.

The advantages of that are:

- can be evaluated at compile-time, and you won't have runtime errors
- you can specialize `bar_trait` without touching `bar`
- you can reuse `bar_trait` at other places that might need to know the size of `FooN` so less code repetition.
- no requirement for marcos
- template argument deduction sill works

```
struct Foo1 {};
struct Foo4 {};
struct Foo8 {};
struct Foo16 {};

// create a declaration for bar_trait but no definition so that specializations are required
template<typename T>
struct bar_trait;

// create the specializations for `Foo1`, `Foo4`, …
template<>
struct bar_trait<Foo1> {
    static constexpr const size_t size = 1;
};

template<>
struct bar_trait<Foo4> {
    static constexpr const size_t size = 4;
};

template<>
struct bar_trait<Foo8> {
    static constexpr const size_t size = 8;
};

template<>
struct bar_trait<Foo16> {
    static constexpr const size_t size = 16;
};

// accepts any type for T as long as a specialization for `bar_trait<T>` exists
// and the expressions applied on `foo` are valid
template<typename T> void bar(T * foo)
{
    constexpr const auto N = bar_trait<T>::size;

    for(unsigned int i=0;i<N;++i)
    {
        //Some critical code that optimizes nicely with SSE, AVX, etc...
    }
}

int main()
{
   Foo1 foo1;
   Foo4 foo4;

   bar(&foo1);
   bar(&foo4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the following convenience class template, `Foo_number_taker`:

```
template<typename> struct Foo_number_taker;
```

Then, with the help of the following macro, `DEF_FOO_NUMBER_TAKER`:

```
#define DEF_FOO_NUMBER_TAKER(N) template<> \
                                struct Foo_number_taker<Foo##N> { \
                                   static constexpr unsigned value = N; \
                                };
```

You can easily specialize the `Foo_number_taker` class template above for `Foo1`, `Foo4`, `Foo8` and `Foo16`:

```
DEF_FOO_NUMBER_TAKER(1)
DEF_FOO_NUMBER_TAKER(4)
DEF_FOO_NUMBER_TAKER(8)
DEF_FOO_NUMBER_TAKER(16)
```

For example, `DEF_FOO_NUMBER_TAKER(8)` will expand to:

```
template<> struct Foo_number_taker<Foo8> { static constexpr unsigned value = 8; };
```

Therefore, it will somehow associate the type `Foo8` with the number *8*, and the macro prevents erroneous associations (e.g., associating `Foo8` with the number *4*) from happening. Analogously for the remaining specializations.

Optionally, you can define the following variable template just for convenience:

```
template<typename FooN>
static auto constexpr Foo_number_v = Foo_number_taker<FooN>::value;
```

Finally, you define your `bar()` function template to take advantage of this variable template above to find out the number associated with the template parameter `FooN`:

```
template<typename FooN>
void bar(FooN* foo) {
   auto constexpr N = Foo_number_v<FooN>;

   for(unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Using it is straightforward:

```
auto main() -> int {
   Foo1 *f1;
   Foo4 *f4;

   // ...

   bar(f1);
   bar(f4);
}
```